# Равномерное позиционирование элементов с помощью Flexbox

Tags: html, css, firefox, flexbox, position

Стилизую круглые точки - они должны равномерно лечь на отрезок. Почему в `Chrome` работает так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А в `FireFox` работает вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пример стилей:

```
.da-dots{
    width: 50%;
    margin: auto;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: row;
    position: relative;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    display: flex;
    height: 100vh;
    padding-top: 20%;
    justify-content: space-between;
    z-index: 2000;
}

.da-dots {
    span{
        width: 12px;
        height: 12px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        z-index: 1;
        position: relative;
        background: #e4b42d;
        cursor: pointer;
        box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.1) inset,1px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,.1);
    }
}

.line_progress{
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #2c3e50;
}
```

Comment: Копать нужно в сторону префиксов

Comment: Для тех, кто в танке - перед постингом вопросов, стоит ознакомится с правилами оформления и правилами хорошего тона.

Comment: @Other, я новенький, мне прощается ;))

Comment: Как раз наоборот - нужно сразу новичку показать его ошибку, чтобы не было повторений. А когда новичок так нагло огрызается или, хотя бы, не признаёт ошибку, призывают Зевса с бан-молотом. Намёк понятен?

Comment: @Other, да шучу я, чего ты так сразу за молотком то))

Comment: Мы все любим пошутить, но это не шутка. И общество согласно, судя по оценкам моих комментариев.

Comment: @Other, Приношу свои извинения высокопочтенный сударь, с правилами ознакомлюсь сию минуту)

Comment: Сразу бы так. И уважение необходимо!

Comment: @Other, Ступайте господин, время отвечать на вопросы!!!))

Answer (score 4):

Это из-за особенностей работы Фаерфокса с `justify-content: space-between` и `position: absolute`.

Рекомендую вам сделать отдельную обертку для точек с `display: flex` и остальными свойствами для флексбокса.

```css
.da-dots {
  width: 50%;
  margin: auto;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  z-index: 2000;
  padding: 20px 0 0;
}
.da-dots__inner {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row;
      -ms-flex-direction: row;
          flex-direction: row;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
      -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
          flex-wrap: wrap;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
      -ms-flex-pack: justify;
          justify-content: space-between;
}
.da-dots span {
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
  background: #e4b42d;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset, 1px 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
}

.line_progress {
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  left: 0;
  top: 25px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<nav class="da-dots">
  <div class="da-dots__inner">
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
  </div>
  <div class="line_progress"></div>
</nav>
```

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/sandmanisdancing/pen/XjyYBz)

Comment: Безотносительно смысла ответа: здесь не поощряются ссылки на сторонние ресурсы, в том числе песочницы, без собственно кода. Кроме того здесь есть встроенная "песочница" движок позволяет встраивать небольшие html/css/js сниппеты прямо в ответ. Ответы типа "все вместе со сниппетом" обычно ценятся больше

Comment: @Sasha Omelchenko, знаете какой-нибудь ещё вариант решения? 
Дело в том что данную разметку генерирует плагин, поэтому внести в неё изменения довольно проблематично

Comment: @GoodNew5 можете при помощи яваскрипта сделать нужные вам манипуляции с DOM, потому что сделать иначе, вероятно, нельзя, поскольку это особенность работы браузера.