# Почему в Firefox и IE абсолютно позиционированный псевдоэлемент вмешивается в расчет space-between?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, firefox, flexbox

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В примере кода в верхнем блоке `.wrapper` есть `::after`. В нижнем его нет. Как сделать чтобы в верхнем положение дочерних элементов расчитывалось правильно, согласно свойству `space-between`?

Вешать `::after` на `.item:last-child` – это не вариант.

Посмотрел в разных браузерах. В Chrome и Opera этого глюка нет, но есть в IE и Firefox.

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100vw;
  border: 1em solid green;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
.wrapper:first-child::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, .4);
  z-index: 10;
}
.item {
  flex-basis: 15vw;
  height: 3em;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Это известный баг ФФ — http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/580418/%D0%9D%D1%83-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%8F-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%8E-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA/580431#580431

Comment: @SashaOmelchenko можно ли решить без изменения html?

Comment: Мне такие способы неизвестны.

Comment: @AndreyFedorov Можете отредактировать вопрос, добавив метку Firefox и уточнить что вопрос про Firefox в теле и заголовке вопроса?

Comment: У FF с флексом всё очень и очень плохо. Подобную проблему сам наблюдал не раз.

Comment: @VostokSisters что конкретно вы имеете в виду под "всё очень и очень плохо" в ff со флексом, кроме описанного в вопросе бага?

Answer (score 1):

Ура! Баг поправлен в firefox v52.

Answer (score 0):

Это из-за особенностей работы IE и FireFox с `justify-content: space-between` и `position: absolute`.

Рекомендую вам сделать отдельную обертку для блоков с `display: flex` и остальными свойствами для флексбокса или же не использовать абсолютно позиционированные элементы внутри блока с `justify-content: space-between`.