# Flex, space-between и псевдо-элементы

Tags: css3, css-animation, flexbox

Работаю с `display: flex` и столкнулся с такой вот проблемкой. Если использовать псевдокласс `:before` или `:after` растягивая блоки внутри родителя через `justify-content:space-between`, то появляется отступ сбоку, даже если элемент в абсолютной позиции. Пример:

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 30px auto;
  background: #eee;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
div:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 15px;
  background: #999;
}
```

```html
<div><span>1</span><span>2</span></div>
```

Проявляется в Firefox, в Chrome проблем нет. На других не тестировал. Есть ли простое решение, кроме очевидных с `float`, оборачиванием в еще один блок и т.д. Спасибо!

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/613934/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%B2-firefox-%D0%B8-ie-%D0%B0%D0%B1%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82-%D0%B2%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%B2-%D1%80%D0%B0#comment846365_613934

Comment: Решение есть - не использовать абсолютно позиционированные элементы внутри блока с `justify-content: space-between`.

Comment: Я так понимаю, что решений моего вопроса нет. Единственный вариант - обернут родителя в блок.

Comment: @AlexeyGiryayev нужно просто понять, что flexbox - не панацея, и не стоит юзать его везде подряд.

Comment: @Vadizar да я в общем-то его и использовал только для вертикального выравнивания элементов. Но, он набирает популярность и самое время взвешенно тестировать работу с ним. Именно от такой работы и возник вопрос.

Comment: @AlexeyGiryayev нужно уметь работать, но ненужно применять везде подряд. Популярность набирает, потому что с помощью него можно быстро сделать не думая. А для вашей задачи есть уже минимум 4 варианта: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/620372/Как-вертикально-отцентрировать-блок-в-контейнере?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 1):

Пока что решение одно: не использовать абсолютно позиционированные элементы внутри блока с `justify-content: space-between`. Для решение вашей задачи с вертикальным выравниваем советую вам эти решения:

## 6 способов центрирования элемента неизвестного размера по вертикали и горизонтали

**Вариант №1: table-cell**

Самый древний вариант, которым пользовались на заре Интернета и во времена рассвета табличной вёрстки. Таблицами уже давно никто не верстает, но можно имитировать их поведение через CSS ради достижения результата:

```css
.block {
   height: 380px; /* for Demo only */
   background: black; /* for Demo only */
   display: table;
   width: 100%;
}

.block-cell {
   display: table-cell;
   text-align: center;
   vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
   <div class="block-cell">
         <img src="https://1000.tech/img/team/01.jpg">
   </div>
</div>
```

**Вариант №2: position absolute**

Один из моих любимых вариантов. Идеально подходит для позиционирования попапов – они должны быть поверх остального контента, а их высота никогда неизвестна, как и высота экрана пользователя.

```css
.block {
   height: 380px; /* for Demo only */
   background: black; /* for Demo only */
   position: relative;
}

.block img {
   position: absolute;
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
   transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
    <img src="https://1000.tech/img/team/01.jpg">
</div>
```

**Вариант №3: line-height**

Один из самых глупых вариантов, который хоть и подходит для выравнивание блока неизвестной высоты, но требует фиксированную высоту родителя (в других способах высота родителя указана лишь для примера). Кстати, этот способ также не подойдет для многострочного текста.

```css
.block {
   background: black; /* for Demo only */
   line-height: 380px;
   text-align: center;
}

.block img {
   vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
   <img src="https://1000.tech/img/team/01.jpg">
</div>
```

**Вариант №4: центрирование через псевдоэлемент**

Мой самый любимый способ. Несмотря на то, что в последнее время стал использовать flexbox – выравнивание через псевдоэлемент навсегда останется в моём сердце.

```css
.block {
   height: 380px; /* for Demo only */
   background: black; /* for Demo only */
   text-align: center;
}

.block:before {
   content: '';
   height: 100%;
   display: inline-block;
   vertical-align: middle;
}

.block img {
   display: inline-block;
   vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
   <img src="https://1000.tech/img/team/01.jpg">
</div>
```

**Вариант №5: Flexbox**

Один из современных и самых простых способов центрирования – использование `display: flex`.

```css
.block {
   height: 380px; /* for Demo only */
   background: black; /* for Demo only */
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
   <img src="https://1000.tech/img/team/01.jpg">
</div>
```

**Вариант №6: CSS Grid**

Grid – наше ближайшее и светлое будущее! Никогда прежде выравнивание блоков не была такой простой и вряд ли в скором времени что-то превзойдет CSS Grid. Хотя этот пример и похож очень на предыдущий, возможности Grid гораздо шире. В общем, если не научились работать с flexbox – можете смело его пропускать и разбираться с CSS Grid.

```css
.block {
   height: 380px; /* for Demo only */
   background: black; /* for Demo only */
   display: grid;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
   <img src="https://1000.tech/img/team/01.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: Вопрос о вертикальном выравнивании не стоял. Задачу я уже давно решил. Интересовал только этот конкретный пример. Об отсутствии решения данной проблемы я уже понял, но, спасибо за примеры.

Comment: @AlexeyGiryayev вы сами так написала "да я в общем-то его и использовал только для вертикального выравнивания элементов. Но, он набирает популярность и самое время взвешенно тестировать работу с ним. Именно от такой работы и возник вопрос. "

Comment: имелось ввиду, что flexbox не является для меня панацеей и я не использую его практически нигде, кроме вертикального выравнивания (с которым проблем нет).